# How do i ge the time difference between different prices in kdb

Tags: kdb

This is the table I have:

```
tab:([]date:2024.01.02;time:(10:01;10:02;10:04;10:09;10:20;10:30;11:01;11:05;11:30;11:44);sym:`MSFT;price:1 1 1 3 3 3 1 1 4 4)
```

I would like to get the time difference. For example, first price 1 and the last price 1, the time difference is 10:04 - 10:01 which is 3 minutes.

The prices are not in regular intervals, it may keep changing or staying the same
price may be the same a bit later like 10 10 10 9 9 9 8 8 10 10 9 9
but i would like measure every intervals and not overlap with the same price intervals later on

I tried to get select last time by date,sym,time,price from tab but it did not work.
If I would like include more sym, how would it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You possibly want something like

```
q)tab:([]date:2024.01.02;time:(10:01;10:02;10:04;10:09;10:20;10:30;11:01;11:05;11:30;11:44);sym:`MSFT;price:1 1 1 3 3 3 1 1 4 4)
q)select first price,diff:max[time]-min time by sym,seq:sums differ price from tab
sym  seq| price diff
--------| -----------
MSFT 1  | 1     00:03
MSFT 2  | 3     00:21
MSFT 3  | 1     00:04
MSFT 4  | 4     00:14
```

EDIT: edited answer above to account for new requirements. As mentioned before you might find strange behaviour in practice if prices are floats since float comparison tolerance might invalidate some of the sequence grouping of "same" prices

Comment: yes price may be back to the same. like 10 10 10 9 9 9. 10 10 10.

Comment: i would like to measure every internals, so if the same price appear again, it is considering new interval

Comment: Ok. Provide an example and what you expect output to look like, thanks

Comment: tab:([]date:2024.01.02;time:(10:01;10:02;10:04;10:09;10:20;10:30;11:01;11:05;11:30;11:44);sym:`MSFT;price:1 1 1 3 3 3 1 1 4 4). so first three, 3 min,21 min for second three, and next two is 4 min and then 14 min.

Comment: Edited answer above